# .htaccess file config for google-apps domain verification exception

Tags: html, google-apps

my current htaccess content is :

```
# @package Mambo Open Source
# @copyright (C) 2005 - 2006 Mambo Foundation Inc.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
#
# Mambo was originally developed by Miro (www.miro.com.au) in 2000. Miro assigned the copyright in Mambo to The Mambo Foundation in 2005 to ensure
# that Mambo remained free Open Source software owned and managed by enter code herethe community.
# Mambo is Free Software
##

#
#  mod_rewrite in use
#

RewriteEngine On

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL 
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update YourMamboDirectory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /YourMamboDirectory

#
#  Rules
#

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^content/(.*) index3.php
RewriteRule ^component/(.*) index3.php
RewriteRule ^mos/(.*) index3.php
```

I would like to verify my google apps domain using HTML upload. But I receive error page 404 when access to the url mydomain.com/google00ff0108e32428b8.html.

I am still receiving the same error page after follow the guideline from 
[Codeigniter .htaccess file config for google-apps domain verification exception

Please help me to allow the domain verification url in htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule google00ff0108e32428b8.html google00ff0108e32428b8.html [L]
```

should do

Comment: This is the correct answer, provided it comes first in the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223434/codeigniter-htaccess-file-config-for-google-apps-domain-verification-exception) And the answer was pretty clear, you can also use other methods to verify your domain using googles webmaster tools, like using cname, and txt records. as well as meta tags.